# AVR regulation brushless vs. brush alternator

Tags: voltage-regulator, alternator

I am currently looking for an AVR for a brush alternator. Today, brushless alternators seem to be more common and so is the supply for AVRs to work for brushless alternators.

My assumption is that the basis principle of an AVR is to sense alternator output voltage and to adjust excitation power.

So what is the difference in design principle of an AVR for a brush vs. brushless alternator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A brush alternator, with a static exciter, uses brushes to directly connect the rotor coils. This is expensive, it needs a lot of current and brushes that need regular replacing. The control electronics are big and expensive.

The brushless alternator uses an additional stator coil magnetized by the AVR called Field. A rotating exciter coil, followed by rectifier diodes on the rotating part generates the main rotor current.  This is cheap, since you need little current on the Field to generate a high current on the rotor. No wear on brushes, and cheap electronics.

See this image [from this site](http://emadrlc.blogspot.com/2013/01/chapter-3-generator-excitation-and.html):
[image: excitation types]

a) is only used on very large machines with very high excitation currents. Like power plants.
b) a brush alternator.
c) a brushless alternator.

---

The advantages and disadvantages change when you're looking at tiny sub 1kVa generators, like in your car. Those are a different class of machines, more like a dynamo. It's cheaper to replace the entire unit instead of only the AVR.

Comment: Unless I misinterpret your answer ... it does not answer my question. The questions was about AVRs being sold for brush and brushless alternators. My understanding is that the purpose of the AVR is to regulate the exciting field. And it will have to do so regardless whether the generator type is brushless or with brushes. I would like to know in what design aspect AVRs need to differ between a brushless and a brush alternator - if there is any difference at all.

Comment: @JohnDoe Nothing, just the size. However, brush AVR's often are controller rectifiers instead of half bridges due to their size.

Answer (score 0):

I am doubtful about you supposition that a brushless alternator requires less current in the excitor stator than a brushed one does for the rotor.  They both need the same magnetic field generated in the rotor, the brushless one has the loss of the magnetic coupling to the rotor.

Comment: _"I am doubtful about you supposition that a brushless alternator requires less current in the excitor stator than a brushed one does for the rotor."_ - The AC exciter is basically a small alternator, which only needs a small field current to generate high output current (the required power coming from mechanical shaft rotation). A brushed exciter needs to supply the full rotor current directly. That makes the AVR larger and more expensive, as he said.

Comment: Small PM alternator ?  Caption said that those were only used in power-station scale generators.  How about the ones that have an exciter coil in the stator (parallel to the power coils), picked up by the rotor coil, then rectified ?  Bootstrap by residual magnetism in the rotor.

Comment: "Caption said that those were only used in power-station scale generators." - and for large generators the 'supposition' is true for the methods of excitation shown. He also says "The advantages and disadvantages change when you're looking at tiny sub 1kVa generators, like in your car.".  A car alternator regulator excites the field coil directly from the battery, whether brushed or brushless. The OP was very vague, but I bet he just had a car alternator or something similar.